# MySQL versus SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

Did the recent purchase of MySQL by Sun and the subsequent buggy releases kill the MySQL brand?

I whole heartedly embraced MySQL when it first came out as I used to be a poor developer and all the RDBMs were too expensive.  I have fond feelings for MySQL and their being able to compete with Oracle and SQL Server.  I credit the original MySQL team for the existence SQL Server Express.  I now use SQL Server Express instead of MySQL for just about everything.  First, I do not like Sun and second, SQL Server Express is significantly more robust and 'Enterprise' than MySQL.

The only significant limitations on SQL Server Express are the 4GB db size and the lack of Agent.  I find that the size limit is not a concern because by the time the db gets close to that size, the application should either be profitable (and you buy the license), or you should kill the product.  The Agent issue is a nice to have, but not critical as you can work around it.

It seems that for db simpletons like me, SQL Server Express is easier to setup and use and is faster and more stable.  And for gurus, they will use PostgresSQL...

Resolved:

So basically, we have a bunch of SQL Server fans (albeit open-minded) on stackoverflow.  It looks like I'm in the right place.  It's sad to see MySQL transform from something you cheer to something you pity.  I hope the founders of the original company try a new endeavor.  I absolutely do not judge them for selling to SUNW - work is naturally profit driven.  I hope we get some people with FU money who don't care about profits who create some products like MySQL used to be.  Othewise, MSFT might take away EXPRESS.

Comment: And who do you think at the back of PostgreSql?

Comment: actually - i don't know who backs postgresql.  i thought it was community.  Are they owned by a corporation as well?

Comment: +1 For a good question.  Don't know why it was at -4 when I first read it.

Comment: **I credit the original MySQL team for the existence SQL Server Express.** Very true. But this is economics/politics. Typically, this starts opinionated arguments - flamewars. Hence people may avoid or discourage such questions. Your points are very valid. And MySQL has some undeniable advantages - **cross-platform** for instance. I think as developers, **we should not worry about the future of MySQL**. **1000s of internet companies depend on MySQL for their existence**. **It will NOT so happen that MySQL will die off due to funding or developer shortage.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having worked with both, I have to say that the limitations and/or bugs in MySQL were a big turn off for me... I don't like PHP, and while I respect the open source community for their advances with these two technologies I just can't see the elegance in the way either of them have been put together.  But don't let my personal taste sway your judgement against MySQL.

I do all of my prototyping in SQL Server Express and most of my clients use full blown SQL Server 2005.  The ease of transition from one to the other makes it a no brainer for me - I can take anything I wrote for SQL Server Express and put it straight in without worrying that the syntax might be different.  The two limitations don't even really get in the way in a dev environment - it's only when you come to production that they would tend to be a problem.

For me, SQL Server wins the argument hands down.

Answer (score 5):

So far no-one knows what Oracle is going to do to MySQL, not even Oracle.

I've done extensive testing of MySQL and would say that in terms of performance it is about at SQL Server 7.0 level.  That is fine if all you need is the performance of SQL Server 7.0

At the enterprise level is simply doesn't compete.  If you look at the fanfare surrounding MySQL 5.4 it says "now supports more than 4 processors".

Where MySQL scores highly is that it is so cheap that it makes a scale-out design feasible, in which case the raw power of an individual box simply doesn't matter.

There are quite a few ommissions in MySQL that will trap a SQL Server developer.  No CHECK constraints, no index views, no separation of clustered indexes from primary keys.  That said, it has a large number of useful features that are very useful to web developers.

The Sun/MySQL guys are remarkably honest about their product.  They say exactly what the strengths and weaknesses are.  If you are used to some of the big vendors sales tactics this comes as a massive shock.  Ultimately this does inspire confidence in using the product because you know exactly what to expect.  I would much sooner deal with a product that says "don't do this because this is beyond our limits" than one that says "our product is the cure for cancer" and it turns out it couldn't cure a simple hangover!

Answer (score 3):

Having run both*, I don't think there's much question that SQL Server is overall a more full-featured product than MySQL (although I'd be interested to hear arguments to the contrary).

I wouldn't be overly concerned with MySQL bugs - just run a few releases behind.

Given that you have a Windows server, the only issue I can see is the prospect of acquiring a significant cost if you max out the resources permitted with Express and need to go to a full, licensed SQL Server 2005 (or 2008) instance. If you expect to scale to that level and can't afford the licence, then a free DBMS would seem to be the smart move now, and I'd also look at PostgreSQL, which may be a better alternative.

* and liked them both for different reasons, FWIW

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old article.  With MySQL 5.7.20 now, there is no reason to use MS SQL Server or any other commercial licensed database.  We switched to MySQL for our high profile financial .Net app six months ago after getting tired with over $50K licensing cost for MS SQL server and this was the best decision ever.  No licensing cost and MySQL is highly configurable, small foot print, performance better than MS SQL servers.  So far no glitches, no issues. Replication is easy to setup and works like a charm.  Did I mention, no money even when running on a 32 core server and having five replication server.  MS SQL server costs $3000 per two core (in our setup this would come out to be in six figures).  Pure stupidity to throw that money out for nothing.  Our own benchmarks, MySQL is performing better than MS SQL server.  We really like easily configurable events in MySQL in addition to it being free.  Just one another point, it takes only a few minutes to install MySQL while it takes forever to install MS SQL server on a new computer.  Don't know what MS SQL server needs to do for hours while MySQL zip file can be unzipped and two line command can configure it within minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the update Allen.  As we review licensing, we're going to have to consider migrating back to MySQL - I hope they've done a lot of catching up.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is still going strong, and will continue to.

Note however that SQL Server Express is limited in other ways; specifically, number of CPUs and limitation of RAM usage (1 GB).

Personally I prefer SQL Server over MySQL. It is much easier to work with. And applications properly developed for it can scale to enterprise level if you are careful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you liking Sun or the mySQL 'brand' should influence your choices too much - unless you feel mySQL will be run into the ground by Sun.  Look at the performance, management and features.

SQL Express with advanced features looks interesting - now has reporting services.  SQL Express also requires a windows license and any associated licensing you might need.

mysql could use http://jasperforge.org/ for reporting.

I like writing tsql more, but for any independent projects, I would likely use mysql due to its cost savings that could be passed on to the client - putting me above the competition.  People like saving money, even if it is profit.

Comment: have you read the latest posts by MySQL insiders?

SUN is driving MySQL into the ground...

Comment: @mson  been 9 years since then, MySQL is thriving.